# Adjust layout to fit for every content Android

Tags: android, xml

I have some customized shape for one layout background, but some content is mixed up depends on what content i open.

I will show you now three images:

1.
[image: 1.]

2.
[image: 2.]

3.
[image]

How could i simplify this layout and if you can see, the layout size changes depends on size of text and if there is image in it.

This is how my layout looks:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/parent_container"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/bg_dialog"
            android:fillViewport="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_status"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                    android:src="@drawable/user_profile_image"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_profile_name"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_timestamp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtStatusMsg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/btn_like"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:button="@drawable/like_button_state"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/btn_like_text"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_like"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_comment"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_comment"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_comment"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/btn_comment_text"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_comment"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_share"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_share"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_report"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="REPORT"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_info"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_report"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_category"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv_category"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Category:"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_category"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_info"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="#Good Night"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My layout is expending when i open image in it or text is bigger than usual. I want to have a clean and smooth layout there like in first picture.

Comment: You should consider to use a ScrollView for the content of your shape. This way long messages won't interfere with the height of your custom shape and the user will scroll the content.

Comment: You are using a ScrollView but outside of the actual content. Move it inside your custom shape.

Comment: I can't. ScrollView background is used for transparent background so the dialog looks better.

Comment: Try swtiching the ScrollView with a RelativeLayout, maintaining background, height and width set to match_parent and fillviewport to false. The add the ScrollView to wrap the message content.

Comment: The whole content is moving in child container layout if i do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111170/discussion-between-matei-radu-and-dusan-dimitrijevic).